# How to find out the percentage of vowels in a string?

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

```
package scanner;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessSentence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type a sentence");
        String sentence = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You entered the sentence " + sentence);
        System.out.println("The number of words in the sentence is " + sentence.length());

        char [] chars=sentence.toCharArray();

        int count = 0;
        for (char c : chars) {
            switch(c) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The numner of vowels in your sentence is " + count);
        System.out.println("The percentage of vowels is " + 100 * count /sentence.length() + "%" );
    }
}
```

Thank you to everyone who helped, I was able to get the correct outcome which i was looking for so i appreciate all the help recieved.

Comment: "_However, i do not get the percentage of vowels_" Well, it is there in the output `The percentage of vowels is 2%`. Do you mean that it is just not correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the result of 1/3 == 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Answer (score 2):

You want `(100.0 * count / sentence.length())`. You're using the `%` operator which is the modulo of two numbers

Answer (score 1):

When you calculate the percent you do:

```
sentence.length() % count
```

But `%` is the modulo operator, which calculates remainder. You wanted to divide:

```
sentence.length() / count
```

However this will still not get you the right results as the scale is not right, and you are dividing incorrectly. It should be:

```
100 *count / sentence.length()
```

Or

```
100.0 *count / sentence.length()
```

If you want to avoid truncation

***Output:***

```
You entered the sentence Hello World
The number of words in the sentence is 11
The numner of vowels in your sentence is 3
The percentage of vowels is 27%
```

Comment: When dealing with percentage its usually better to use a floating point `100.0` rather than an integer to avoid truncation.

Comment: @flakes Not necessarily.  Rounding to the next integer below is probably exactly what OP wants.

Comment: i also believe i need to add a float, but do not know where i would add this, the code you wrote has helped me so thank you

Comment: @Satoshi1999 What do you mean by add a float?

Comment: Nevermind, just made the correct changes and everything is correct, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are not using correct operator. modulus(%) gives you the remainder after the division. You need to use division (/) operation. You may want to use double/float for getting accurate value.